# How will Dropbox work in a third data partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, dropbox, google-drive

I will try to explain my situation, but neither my first nor my second language is English...

I study a Telecommunications degree and I have a HP Spectre x360, that works really well. This year we are studying various transmission protocols, such as TCP or ARP, and we are using a lot Linux (Debian in class but I don't like it and I want to try Ubuntu). So, I'm thinking of making a partition and installing Ubuntu. Actually I'm planning of making three different partitions on my SSD: one for Windows, another for Ubuntu, and the third one for data. I think I won't have any trouble making the partitions and installing Ubuntu (it's not my first time installing Linux distributions) but I have an important question that no one in my environment was able to solve.

I like to use Dropbox/OneDrive/GoogleDrive in order to keep my files (some days I feel lazy and I bring my iPad to class instead of my laptop) and I was asking myself if I could keep the GoogleDrive data in the third partition and associate it in each operating system the same folder to sync. That would be awesome and it wouldn't matter if you are on Windows or Ubuntu, because in each case your folders will be synced!

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I imagine that you could map to the partition and folder for Dropbox, et al, as long as you have access from both OS partitions. I would make the data partition NTFS, since you are going to have Windows as well. There is an option in Dropbox to choose which folders you want to sync.

Comment: @Syd Though NTFS has many problems with the Fast Boot feature of Windows, i think Fat32 would have less problems. Though You will have some limitations.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answers! Apparently I have a new deal because Dropbox on Linux will not support NTFS partitions since November, only ext4 partitions, and Windows don't support ext4 partitions….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use symbolic links in Ubuntu Dropbox

I have not tried this, but it may work.

- Follow the first part of the answer
  [How will Dropbox work in a third data partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086777/how-will-dropbox-work-in-a-third-data-partition/1086793#1086793)
  to move the Dropbox folder from within Windows.
- Create a folder within the Dropbox folder to keep your files and
  folders. Lets call this folder **InDropbox** folder. If `E:\` is the
  data partition, your folder structure may look like
  `E:\Dropbox\InDropbox`.
- Move all your folders and files you normally sync inside `E:\Dropbox\InDropbox`.
- **Reboot to Ubuntu.**
- Make sure the NTFS data partition is mounted at boot time with appropriate changes in `/etc/fstab`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions
- **Pause Dropbox sync.**
- Open the `/home/$USER/Dropbox` folder in Nautilus. Delete the InDropbox folder if it exists.
- Open a second Nautilus window and navigate to `/NTFS_Data_Partition_Mountpoint/Dropbox/`.
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag using the mouse the `InDropbox` folder from `/NTFS_Data_Partition_Mountpoint/Dropbox` to `/home/$USER/Dropbox`. This will create a symbolic link of the InDropbox folder in the data partition inside the Dropbox folder in your Home.
- Rename the folder `Link to InDropbox` to `InDropbox`. The Linux version of Dropbox understands symbolic links.
- Resume Dropbox sync within Ubuntu. Now Dopbox should sync to the `InDropbox` folder in the data partition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will investigate a Little bit more on symbolic links but I think your tutorial will work without problem. So thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a native dropbox app for Linux, but nothing from the Microsoft and Google for OneDrive and GoogleDrive respectively.

## Dropbox is ending `NTFS` support in Linux systems on November 7, 2018. Only `ext4` file system will be supported in Linux system and `NTFS` will only be supported in Windows.

## The original answer below will not work!

## Partition setup

Your idea of three partitions, one for Windows, second for Ubuntu, and third for data is fine. Make the data partition NTFS, so that both Windows and Ubuntu can read it. In the data partition create a folder that Dropbox would sync.

## Dropbox setup

### In Windows

Dropbox sync folder usually is at `C:\Users\<username>`. Once you have setup Dropbox in Windows you can move the Dropbox folder to your data partition using the method described in [How to change the location of your Dropbox folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/246590/how-to-change-the-location-of-your-dropbox-folder/)

The main steps are:

Click the Dropbox icon in your system tray, click the Settings icon, and then choose Preferences.

[image]

In the Dropbox Preferences window, switch to the Account tab. Next to the current folder location, click Move.

[image]

Browse for the data partition. A folder named Dropbox will be created inside it any folder you choose, so don’t create a new folder named “Dropbox”–just pick the folder you want your “Dropbox” folder to reside in. Click OK.

### In Ubuntu

Make sure the **Multiverse** repositories are active. Install Dropbox using the **Ubuntu Software** app and set up as usual.

Click the Dropbox icon in the top panel, click the Settings icon, and then choose Preferences.

[image]

In the Dropbox Preferences window, switch to the Sync tab. Next to the Dropbox  folder location, click Move.

[image]

Browse for the data partition. A folder named Dropbox should already be there if you moved the folder from Windows there. **Choose the parent folder of that Dropbox folder** and click OK.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your tutorial!
I've been searching for what you say about Dropbox not supporting NTFS partitions no more and here's a link for example: https://itsfoss.com/dropbox-linux-ext4-only/
What I read is that Dropbox on Linux will only support ext4 partitions (and Windows NTFS) and apparently Windows does not support ext4 partitions…
Said that, what are my options??
Thank you so much!